# Sphinx PDF output does not include auto-generated documentation from code

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, autodoc

I use the following `conf.py` for a python project. The html generated files is nice and provide the auto generated documents from the codes, but the pdf file is almost empty and only includes conents in the rst files.

```py
import os
import sys
import stanford_theme

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo',
              'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
              'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
              # 'sphinxcontrib.plantuml',
              'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram',
              'sphinx.ext.coverage',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
              'sphinx.ext.imgmath',
              'sphinx.ext.mathjax'
              ]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build']
html_theme = 'stanford_theme'
html_theme_path = [stanford_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
html_static_path = ['_static']


latex_elements = {
    'papersize': 'letterpaper',
    'pointsize': '12pt',
    'preamble': r"""
\usepackage{setspace}
"""
}
```

I use

```sh
make latex
cd build/latex
make
```

to produce pdf file.
How do I make pdf files including the autogenerated docs from the source codes.
I am using Sphinx(I think the latest version) on Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Comment: Probably I need to remove the question if it seems too obvious.

Comment: Either delete the question or post an Answer. The solution to a problem should not be in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I found it:
The auto generated code is produced in an rst file:

```
Auto Generated Documentation 
==============================

.. automodule:: visualization
    :members:
```

I reference the file in index.rst

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   code
```